# Unable to start Redis Cluster servers

Tags: bash, macos, redis, macos-sierra, redis-cluster

I'm trying to start the [Redis cluster](https://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial) servers by turning on 6 servers from ports 7000 to 7005, each with a `redis.conf` in their own directories on my macOS  Sierra. I can start the first server fine (either of the 6) and here's that [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Maikf.jpg) and the `info` in the [cli](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/04a5d01906336cf777beff6f4e0bf52d): Here's an example of one of these commands I run, using redis 3.2.1

```
redis-server /private/etc/redis-3.2.1/src/7002/redis.conf
```

but starting another would give this error:

```
11245:M 06 Mar 22:45:22.536 * Increased maximum number of open files to 10032 (it was originally set to 7168).
11245:M 06 Mar 22:45:22.537 # Sorry, the cluster configuration file nodes.conf is already used by a different Redis Cluster node. Please make sure that different nodes use different cluster configuration files.
```

Following the docs, I have each redis.conf configured to this with their corresponding port numbers

```
port 7000
cluster-enabled yes
cluster-config-file nodes.conf
cluster-node-timeout 5000
appendonly yes
```

This used to work for me. I don't know for certain if it's related, but since then I have built these files into Docker images and containers. However, as far as I can tell I have deleted them, and also this file: [/Users/MyUserAccount/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/com.docker.driver.amd64-linux](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/371)

I also just deleted all the directories and recreated them in a different directory, but still it does not work. What can I do to get these ports available for Redis Cluster again?

---

**UPDATE:**

Also, my `nodes.conf` file is not being recreated in any of the port folders, and all of them only has the redis.conf file. Before when it worked, there was a `nodes.conf` file generated with 2 other files (I think a dump file and one other one).

Comment: When you start the first, what does the 'info' command show the config path as? Looks like they are all trying to use the same file for some reason.

Comment: @ChrisTanner here is that [info](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/04a5d01906336cf777beff6f4e0bf52d) and I have updated my question with it as well.

Comment: If a different first server was started I will get a different corresponding config file listed in `info`: e.g. `config_file:/private/etc/redis-3.2.1/src/7004/redis.conf `

Comment: Looks like a `nodes.conf` is being generated from wherever I call redis-server from, and I am able to start the servers if I `cd` into the different directories. This seems kind of inconvenient since before I just had a script that called from a single location the `redis.conf` at their absolute paths. But at least I have some solution.

Comment: You can write an answer to your own question, and mark it as accepted. This will help future visitors!

Comment: Sure, I didn't think it was a great solution, but I suppose it's the best there is at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a nodes.conf is being generated from wherever I call redis-server from, and I am able to start the servers if I cd into the different directories. This seems kind of inconvenient since before I just had a script that called from a single location the redis.conf at their absolute paths. But at least I have some solution.